# 2Python calendar count

Tags: python, calendar

My first day is `2012/01/01`, and I hope I can have a function `get_day(count)`, where:

```
get_day(0) returns 2012/01/01
get_day(1) returns 2012/01/02
get_day(2) returns 2012/01/03
...
```

How can I implement it using python `calendar` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you are looking for

```
def get_day(x):
    d=datetime.strptime('2012/01/01' , '%Y/%m/%d')
    a=(d+timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    return a
get_day(5)
>>>2012/01/06
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the ***datetime*** module to implement (Seems to be simpler with this).

The `start_date` and `end_date` parameters help in adding flexibility to the date format specification.

```
import datetime


def get_date(count, start_date, date_format):
    count_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format) + \
                 datetime.timedelta(days=count)
    return count_date.strftime(date_format)


print(get_date(0, '2012/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d'))
print(get_date(1, '2012/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d'))
print(get_date(2, '2012/01/01', '%Y/%m/%d'))
```

```
Output:
2012/01/01
2012/01/02
2012/01/03
```